# I cant use psiAugmentProvider in a JetBrains plugin project

Tags: java, plugins, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

When I create the project, I try to use the `psiAugmentProvider`, but there is some error from the IDEA:

[image]

This are my `depends`:

[image]

More information: my Java JDK version is 17, and the SDK is cloned from the idea-community. I can't even use the `PsiAugmentProvider` class in Java.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am a beginner of the plugin development. I would be appreciated if someone can give me some useful information. If you need some more details about the problem, please tell me and I will provide it.

I tried to see if I needed to add other dependencies, but all failed.

Comment: What is the error exactly? Can you please provide the error message, too?

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in **plugin.xml**

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>
```

Then add plugins =

> ['com.intellij.java']

to **build.gradle**

intellij configuration.

like

```
intellij {
   plugins = ['com.intellij.java']
}
```

Next your psiAugmentProvider should be found, which is available in idea 2023.3.2